# How to handle the empty spaces in combo box value?

Tags: jquery, html

Following is my code where i am trying to get the value of the comboBox

```
var combValue= $('#combobox option:selected').val();
```

And i am assigning it to

```
<input id="name" value='+combValue+' />'+'</br>
```

But the problem is that when there comes empty space in combValue, it does not show the value after the space.(When i print combValue, Values after the space are not showing)
How can i show the full string including empty space, i am writing my html page using jQuery?

Comment: $('#name input').val(combValue);

Comment: i want to get the complete selected value of the combobox, but it is only showing till space not any thing after the space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not quoting the value in your output, creating ambiguous HTML, causing the browser to have to guess as to where the quotes were supposed to be.  Try this:

```
'<input id="name" value="' + combValue + '" />' + '</br>'
```

Really though, don't concatenate data into HTML.  Set the value programmatically so you don't have to worry about escaping your data:

```
$('<input>').attr('id', 'name').val(combValue);
```